# Can't add a .ldif to OpenLDAP, recent version (no slapd.conf)

Tags: debian, openldap, windows

I'm new to LDAP and I'm trying to add the mmc.ldif and mail.ldif files that come with Mandriva Directory Server to my LDAP configuration, using the command :

> ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=admin,dc=biganon,dc=com" -f schema/mmc.ldif

I then give the admin password I've set during slapd installation but get this error :

> ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)

**I have no slapd.conf file.**

**I'm on Debian 6.0.1, OpenLDAP 2.4.23**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your configuration this is a hard question to answer.  If you shut down `slapd`, you can use `slapcat` to view the current contents of your directory tree and you can use `slapadd` to update the directory.

You can create a `slapd.conf` if you want to use the old-style configuration.  Unless you're making lots of runtime changes to your backend configuration I'm not sure there's a huge advantage to the `cn=config` mechanism.

[This document](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/slapd-config.html) contains instructions for converting FROM slapd.conf TO `cn=config`; it also has instructions for going in the other direction.

Comment: That document doesn't exactly contain full instructions for converting .ldif schemas to .schema, nor does it explain whether this is still necessary. I've found [a script to perform the conversion](https://github.com/dkoudela/active-directory-to-openldap) and tried it; it turns out to be out of date.

Answer (score 0):

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

"Invalid credentials" always means you're using incorrect bind dn or password. Please check them first.